# How would I factor $a^3+b^3+c^3-6abc$

Tags: factoring

How would I factor the polynomial $a^3+b^3+c^3-6abc$? The values are homogenous, so so must be the factors. I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: I don't think there are any factors in the canonical sense. The closest one that you will get is $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$

Comment: Here is an opposite question: find integers $a,b,c$ so that $a^3+b^3+c^3-6abc$ is prime.

Comment: Well 2,1,1 gives a prime but this doesnt imply nonfactorization since one term may be equal to unity.

Comment: It is irreducible; I attempted to factor over $\mathbb C$ and got an impossibility out of it. Why do you think this factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-6abc= (a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+c^3-6abc
\\(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b)c(a+b+c) -3ab(a+b)-6abc
\\=(a+b+c)^3 -3(a+b)c(a+b+c)-3ab(a+b)-(3+3)abc
\\=(a+b+c)^3-3c((a+b)(a+b+c)) -3ab(a+b+c) $$
now factor $$ (a+b+c) $$ and go on
$$(a+b+c)((a+b+c)^2 -3c(a+b) -3ab) )
\\=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2ac+2bc-3ab-3bc-3ac)
\\=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)
$$

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll give this question a little more time to see if a better answer comes up, otherwise I'll accept it

Comment: I think this is what @Ivan put in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work. Over $\mathbb C,$ the closest you can get, with $\beta^3 = 1$ and $\gamma^3 = 1,$ is
$$ (A + \beta B + \gamma C) (A^2 + \beta^2 B^2 + \gamma^2 C^2 - \beta \gamma BC - \gamma CA - \beta AB) = A^3 + B^3 + C^3 - 3 \beta \gamma ABC  $$

Answer (score 0):

Try solving the cubic for $c=x+y$ so that $c^3=(x^3+y^3)+3xy(x+y)=(x^3+y^3)+3xyc$

Whence $x^3+y^3=-a^3-b^3$ and $xy=2ab$ so that $x^3y^3=8a^3b^3$ and $x^3, y^3$ are roots of the quadratic $$z^2+(a^3+b^3)z+8a^3b^3$$ so that $$x^3,y^3=\frac {-a^3-b^3\pm  \sqrt {a^6+b^6-30a^3b^3}}2$$

And use this to build your factors $(c-x-y)(c-\omega x-\omega^2 y)(c-\omega^2 x - \omega y)$ where $\omega$ is a non-trivial cube root of $1$.